# Why Xorg ignores changes in xorg.conf?

Tags: xorg, xorg.conf

I have to pointer devices (mouse and touchscreen). Their devices are `/dev/input/mouse0` and `/dev/input/mouse1`, also they are combined into one on device `/dev/input/mice`. I want my system to separate those devices. I was trying to edit my xorg.conf file, by changing this line in mouse input device section:

```
Option "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
```

to this:

```
Option "Device" "/dev/input/mouse1"
```

and then reloading Gnome Display Manager:

```
service gdm restart
```

After this, system behaves like nothing happened. I am certain that xorg.conf is read on restart - if I write some rubbish into it (change identifier, for example) gdm fails to start. But all other edits have no effect - I event tried to delete the line which specified the device, and nothing happened.

What can cause such behavior? And how can I fix it?

EDIT:

Mouse input device section in xorg.conf:

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "Mouse0"
    Driver "mouse"
    Option "Device" "/dev/input/mice" # tried removing this line, nothing happens
    Option "Protocol" "auto"
    Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection
```

Comment: The `Option "Device" "/path/to/device"` is mandatory, the GDM should fail when you remove it. Could you past the whole section here ? And there's no other InputDevice configured ?

Comment: @woliveirajr - Just tried it again - it has not failed. Yes, there is keyboard configured. I'll post the whole section in a minute.

Comment: Updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this point

> The driver can auto-detect the mouse type on some platforms. On some platforms this is limited to plug and play serial mice, and on some the auto-detection works for any mouse that the OS's kernel driver supports. On others, it is always necessary to specify the mouse protocol in the config file. The README.mouse document contains some detailed information about this.

From [this site](http://ftp.x.org/pub/X11R7.0/doc/html/mouse.4.html).

Also take a look [at the second part of this answer](http://linuxreviews.org/howtos/xfree/mouse/) about USB mice

Comment: Autodetection is cool. But still, why it ignores the "Device" option?

Comment: perhaps something with the correct module (the touchpad one) not being compiled, or loaded... them it autoloads the first it finds.

Comment: I solved my problem (calibrating the touchscreen) without editing xorg.conf after all. Thanks for you help anyway.

Comment: @Rogach thanks for sharing your solution, maybe it help someone with a similar problem!